# texture not showing up in image used as object, a black object is showing

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

[image: In viewport shading when texture is selected, the texture does not show up. had selected image as plane in the beginning.].
This is my first time doing any project. i have just started learning blender and following a tuitorial from youtube to learn cloth simulation . 
selected IMAGE AS PLANE in the beginning.
then did as the tutorial said.
applied force(wind) and played the animation. all worked fine. then when i selected viewport shading in 3d panel to see how it looks with the texture on, the image does not show up as you can see in the screenshot.
this is the tutorial name "Blender Beginner Tutorial: Animated Flag"

NOTE :when i played the animation, the flag is showing up but its too dark unlike in the video.

video link of problem : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ValeTXFpfvxhbRL7fuWk8P-9cdhdH6Ix/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check that there is a light source in the scene, and double check that the normals are correct....

Comment: yes there is light but still . i am following the tutorial step by step

Comment: does it come out black when rendered [F12]? What if you rotate the camera around the other side of the flag? Add a Cube, is lit correctly?

Comment: yes i see a black rectangle , i hope you saw that video as well. and the cube is just lit from top and rest sides are dark unlike in normal scene.

Comment: I did not realise the video included your own footage as well as the tutorial, very good idea for us to use when diagnosing. In your Blender scene there is indeed a light directly above the flag which is the cause of your problem. The tutorial is using Cycles and you are using Blender Internal. I would recommend Cycles and increase the Background colour from dark grey to light grey/white to easily illuminate your scene. But there are lots of ways of getting more/better lighting depending on your requirements. Maybe someone else can chime in on Blender Internal fixes,I have not used it for ages